# What is the value of a limit of sums with $\sin k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is the value of the following limit?

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor 10^t π \rfloor} \sin k $$

I don't know what to do.
I need your help. Thank you.

P.S.

I think series diverges because $lim_{t\to \infty} \sin {\lfloor 10^t π \rfloor}$ is not exist.
To show that, I want to prove that set $S=\{\lfloor 10^t π \rfloor (\text mod 2π) \mid t \in N\}$ is dense in $[0,2π]$ but I can't prove this.

Comment: I suppose that you do not expect to get a number.

Comment: I am sorry. I went outside after post this question. I think this series diverges because of limit test. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

One approach I would suggest is to write $\sin k$ as $Im(e^{ik}$) and realize that the sum forms a geometric series.

If you don't want to do the necessary algebra you can look for Lagrange's identity involving sum of sine. (Just to check your answer)